# Objective-C XMPPFramework Offline Queues

Tags: objective-c, ios, xmppframework

Hoping to find someone familiar with https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki

My application sends and receives messages between other phones running the application and iChat. I'm using a eJabberd installed on a rackspace.

The problem is that if I send a message with my phone to a phone that is offline, the user will not receive the message when they go online in their application (nor will they in iChat - the message is never queued).

However, when I send a message through iChat and then log into my application on my phone, the message comes through just fine.

It would appear that, for whatever reason, the way I am sending messages with the XMPPFramework above is not triggering the queuing feature of the server. I've followed the specifications [here](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0160.html) to send a message that looks exactly like this (with different usernames)

```
    message from='romeo@montague.net/orchard' to='juliet@capulet.com'>
  <body>
    O blessed, blessed night! I am afeard.
    Being in night, all this is but a dream,
    Too flattering-sweet to be substantial.
  </body>
</message>
```

with the same results, unfortunately. I've been trying to find a way to view what the outgoing XML of iChat looks like, but to no avail. Hopefully there is somebody out there who has ran into this issue before.

Comment: Off-line messaging is the responsibility of the XMPP server.  What do your server logs say?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eric. I'll get back to this when I have access to the log again.

Comment: @marklar Did you get anywhere with this? I am also not getting offline messages when I use the library

Answer (score 3):

Off-line messages are the responsibility of the server.  How to handle off-line messages is explained in [XEP-0160: Best Practices for Handling Offline Messages](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0160.html).

On the client side, you'll want to make sure you are sending message stanzas with types of "normal" or "chat".

You'll also want to make sure you have off-line message storage enabled in eJabberd.

Comment: Hey, we are switching from ejabberD to Tigase. I'm building up the chat component of the app. Will get back to this thread with results when I start doing the xmpp components again.

Comment: @eric when we are in offline mode than get message in queue ?
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
 when app is terminate than this method is not call rght ?